# IDictionary w/ Null Key - MSDN Typo or something else going on?

Tags: c#, exception, null, msdn, idictionary

[IDictionary<TKey, TValue>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyxt2e2h.aspx)

> ArgumentNullException - *key* is null.

Then, in the remarks...

> Implementations can vary in whether they allow key to be null.

So, I have to wonder... is this an error or something I'm just missing here? The MSDN help file seems a bit contradictory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What the documentation says is "If you get `ArgumentNullException`, then *key* was null".

It does not say "If *key* is null, you get an `ArgumentNullException`."  That would be an converse logic fallacy.

The complete condition would be:

"If and only if both *key* is null and the container does not support null keys, you get an `ArgumentNullException`."

Comment: incidentally i notice that logic flaw to be the most common reason for invalid arguments (just in general in life, not programming)

Answer (score 1):

The table you're looking at is mapping Outcomes to the Conditions that caused them.

In this case, the exception is caused by a null argument.